# How enable requests from Azure APIM to an App Service with Private Endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-management, azure-virtual-network, azure-private-link

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68264103/azure-app-service-not-accessible-with-private-endpoint-within-apim-vm) but without any solution. So here it goes:

I'm trying to setup an API with the following infrastructure:

AGW -> APIM (with custom domain) -> Web App with API (with private endpoint enabled).
All these resources are in a separate NSG but in the same VNET.

However I keep getting a 401 unauthorized when trying to call the API (see below). The request reaches APIM, but upon "forward-request" it fails. When removing the private endpoint from the app it does work.

I also tried it with a simple Azure Function, with the same result. Making a request while private endpoint is enabled I get a 500 timeout, and without it works fine.

I have

- removed all possible NSG restrictions
- setup private DNS (resolve to private ip, FQDN A record privatelink.azurewebsites.net -> azurewebsites.net)
- enabled access to all ip's in app services & enabled public access for testing

But still to no avail.

So the question is, am I doing something wrong? Is it even possible to call a webapp with a private endpoint from APIM?

the response:

```
forward-request (69.473 ms)
{
    "response": {
        "status": {
            "code": 401,
            "reason": "Unauthorized"
        },
        "headers": [
            {
                "name": "Content-Length",
                "value": "0"
            },
            {
                "name": "Date",
                "value": "Fri, 21 Oct 2022 11:33:00 GMT"
            },
            {
                "name": "WWW-Authenticate",
                "value": "Basic realm=\"site\""
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: is your APIM also in the VNet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course after hours of struggling I find the solution right after posting this question.

'Client certificate mode' in the App Service was set to 'Require' due to a mistake in the Bicep file. Setting this to 'Ignore' (for now) made the app accessible.